# MultiThreading with LinkedList

Tags: c, multithreading, linked-list

I need to make three threads with shared access to linkedlist: searching,adding,removing thread. Seaching thread only browsing through list. Adding threads add item at the end of list and they are mutual exclusive (protected by mutex) but you can searching and adding at the same time. Removing threads remove item from any point at the list and they are mutal exclusive with adding and searching.

My linked list:

```
      struct node
        {
            int data;
            struct node *next;
        }

       void search(int num)
        {
        int flag = 0;
        struct node *temp;

        temp = start;

          while(temp!=NULL)
          {
            if(temp->data == num)
               return(temp); //Found
            temp = temp->next;
          }

          if(flag == 0)
             return(start); // Not found
        }

        void insert(int num)
        {
            int c=0;
            struct node *temp;
            temp=head;
            if(temp==NULL)
            {
            add(num);
            }
            else
            {
            while(temp!=NULL)
            {
                if(temp->data<num)
                c++;
                temp=temp->next;
            }
            if(c==0)
                add(num);
            else if(c<count())
                addafter(num,++c);
            else
                append(num);
            }
        }

int delete(int num)
{
    struct node *temp, *prev;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
    if(temp->data==num)
    {
        if(temp==head)
        {
        head=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
        }
        else
        {
        prev->next=temp->next;
        free(temp);
        return 1;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        prev=temp;
        temp= temp->next;
    }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If anyone could show me way how to do with threads and mutex I will be so thankful

Comment: You already have code for the three functions.  Try putting each on a thread.  Use mutex to protect critical sections.

Comment: A note, how does search return anything? It's a void.

Comment: You messed up your list name. In one function you use `start`, while in others you use `head`. Maybe you should not use global variables for your list at all.

Comment: You also have a broken search function. You cannot distinguish between finding your value in the first node and not finding it at all. You should return `NULL` instead of `start` and of course the function signature must be changed from `void` to `struct node*` as return type.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. See info in this link http://www.cs.nyu.edu/courses/fall05/G22.2631-001/lists.slides2.pdf It is in java but the principles are the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are using pthread.h.

First you should add a struct for you linked list:

```
typedef struct 
        {
            struct node *first;
            pthread_mutex_t list_mutex;
        } *List;
```

And then add `pthread_mutex_lock(&list_mutex);` to the start of each function and `pthread_mutex_unlock(&list_mutex);` to the end.

Also your functions should receive a List as an argument, so you need to change the function definitions.

You should read about Pthread mutex locks.

Comment: This is called coarse grain locking, and it is the base of all methods. If you are to lock the entire list for each operation, then why use multiple threads? Other methods are fine grain locking,  optimistic synchronization, lazy synchronization, non blocking... e.t.c

Comment: The lock I've explained is the simplest under the given rules. I understand I gave the worst way of locking, but without any given assumptions (such as probability of conflict etc.) this seems like the easiest way.